# Unit Test in Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, tdd

I'm not so experience in Objective-C, but I'm I'd like to start develop in iOS using TDD, for this I have few newbie questions :)

What people are using for TDD for iOS? I was think in use the Test framework that already have in Xcode, is it good? or any better options?

I was trying to do some exercises for unit test, and I was creating an Example, where I have a TableViewControllerClass, using CoreLocation, with this methods:

```
    -(void)startFindLocation
    {
        [self.cllManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
    {
        [self.cllManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        CLLocation *actualLocation = [locations lastObject];

        NSLog(@"latitude: %f", actualLocation.coordinate.latitude);
        NSLog(@"longitude: %f", actualLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    }
```

What I would like to test, is very simple, is to see if the CLLocation has a latitude and a longitude, instead of using NSLong.
For that I really need to alloc and init this TableViewController class in my Test Class? or there's any framework, similar to Rspec (for example, ruby/rails), where I can check if a specific label in the application screen has this value of latitude and longitude?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow through on this tutorial to get the basics: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3716/unit-testing-in-xcode-4-quick-start-guide

Then you'll be able to decide how to write your own test suite. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

I have a series of screencasts on iOS TDD, starting with https://qualitycoding.org/objective-c-tdd/

Regarding your particular question, a unit test needs to check results in one of three ways:

1. Return value verification
2. State verification
3. Behavior verification

I don't see anything in -locationManager:didUpdateLocations: that leads to any of these. Perhaps you want to TDD a helper method instead.